# Setting onclicklistener to multi viewpager (gallery widget alternative)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, commonsware, universal-image-loader

I am currently trying to implement a Gallery-like view. Since it has been deprecated i have been trying to find alternatives. I have successfully experimented with Universal Image Loader's image view pager with Dave Smith's implementation of view pager in the following link. http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html The result is a gallery-like widget.

**Edit**
My current problem is that the onclicklistener seems to activate only at the focused page. I have tried to set the onclicklistener to the viewPager instead but the the problem still persists. Any help and advice is appreciated.

Here is a snippet of my code:

**(Updated)My Activity:**

```
public class PagerActivity extends Activity {

PagerContainer mContainer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    //A little space between pages
    pager.setPageMargin(15);

    //If hardware acceleration is enabled, you should also remove
    // clipping on the pager for its children.
    pager.setClipChildren(false);
}

//Nothing special about this adapter, just throwing up colored views for demo
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View page=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.pagetext);
        tv.setText("Item "+position);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));


        final int cPos = position;
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(PagerActivity.this,"Page at: "+String.valueOf(cPos) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                   .show();
            }

        });

        container.addView(page);
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
}
}
```

**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.pagercontainer.PagerContainer
    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</com.example.pagercontainer.PagerContainer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I have updated my version of this sample to register click handlers on each `TextView`, and they all fire as expected: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1

Comment: The example you linked does not make use of a container to wrap around the viewpagers. I am trying out Dave Smith's code which makes use of this container. I think the problem is that only the focused page is able to fire off.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that works for me was this line:

`final int cPos = position;`

I have been trying to figure out how to combine `setOffscreenPageLimit()` with get focused item position. So, making this variable final and then pass it to the onclicklistener it will display the correct item.